# Spring Boot @Autowired does not work with class of different package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The structure of my project like the following:

[image]

I am sure everything okay but only one thing make the problem is @Autowired in `StoredProcedureSpringDataJpaApplication.java` like the following:

```
public class StoredProcedureSpringDataJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository stu;
    
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
         SpringApplication.run(StoredProcedureSpringDataJpaApplication.class, args); 
        
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        List<Student> students = stu.findAll();
        students.forEach(System.out :: println);
        
    }

}
```

Error description is:

> Field stu in com.example.demo.StoredProcedureSpringDataJpaApplication required a bean of type 'com.repository.StudentRepository' that could not be found.

I know this is familiar question ,I did so many way to try to solve this problem in the internet even in stackoverflow but all can not solve my problem.

Help me solve this problem.

Comment: move that `XXXApplication` class to a package like `com`, that is : place it in a "parent" package of all your beans. this is how spring-boot picks up everything by default

Comment: you mean ,place package ```com.repository ``` inside package ```com.example.demo```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@ComponentScan({"com.example.demo", "com.repository"})`

By default without this annotation it considers only annotations that exist inside the package where your `@SpringBootApplication` is declared, aka `com.example.demo`

Also together with the `@ComponentScan` use the following

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.repository"})
```

Comment: I did like you do before but issues the same error

Comment: check if your StudentRepository class has the annotation `@Repository`

Comment: yeah it has  ```@Repository```

Comment: check my updated answer and add also the last annotation together with @Component. It will work

Answer (score 1):

Your package structure is incorrect StoredProcedureSpringDataJpaApplication.java should be in the root package. Another way is component scan placing annotation over StoredProcedureSpringDataJpaApplication.java. In your case, it should be like

[image: package structure]

This won't work for the repository class and as you have a different package structure so `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.repository")` will help you resolve this issue.

Comment: yeah, you are right but I curiously is there any way to solve this problem with above structure?

Comment: @Dunguyen Please see attached directory structure, hope this will help you.

Comment: I did like the way that you show me but still issues the same error

Comment: Can you share the latest directory structure along with the code snippet of StoreProcedureSpringDataJpaApplication and StudenRepository?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `@SpringBootApplication` does only scan in the package where it is defined.

Make sure it is placed at the root of your project and everything that should be scanned below it. For example:

```
com
  - example
      - demo
          - StoredProcedureSpringDataJpaApplication.java
          - repository
              - StudentRepository.java
```

Comment: yeah I did like that before and work fine, but I curiously is there any way to solve this problem with above structure?